# Popup disappear on mouse over

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to display address on map on popup's as shown below in the image.

Image of popup:

[image]

When I hover mouse on pin icon the popup appears but when I move to popup it disappear.

Javascript I am using:

```
  <script>

        jQuery(function($) {
  var pop = $('.map-popup');
  pop.click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });

  $('a.marker').hover(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).next('.map-popup').toggleClass('open');
    $(this).parent().siblings().children('.map-popup').removeClass('open');
  });

  $(document).click(function() {
    pop.removeClass('open');
  });

  pop.each(function() {
    var w = $(window).outerWidth(),
        edge = Math.round( ($(this).offset().left) + ($(this).outerWidth()) );
    if( w < edge ) {
      $(this).addClass('edge');
    }
  });
});



    </script>
```

Code Pen link: [codepen](https://codepen.io/ShahbazEnergy/pen/BaoLMbO?editors=1010)

Comment: Can you provide a code pen or fidde so I can test

Comment: @MannyQuintanilla, here is the link for code pen: https://codepen.io/ShahbazEnergy/pen/BaoLMbO?editors=1010

Comment: What do you expect to happen? Should the popup remain open when you hover over it?

Comment: @Rajat, yes it should remain open when hover over it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
$('a.marker').hover(function(e) {
```

use

```
$('a.marker').mouseenter(function(e) {
```

`hover` handles both mouseenter and mouseleave events. If you don't pass a handler for mouseleave, it will execute the function for mouseenter, so in your case,

```
$(this).next('.map-popup').toggleClass('open');
```

is executed again for `mouseleave` so the popup gets hidden.
Read more [here](https://api.jquery.com/hover/).